# Request not changing

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am requesting to an api with python, library requests, but all of the responses are the same to the first one, even when the data on the api changes. The data of first few responses should be a string 'STATUS-WAIT' and then 'STATUS-OK'.
This is how my function looks:

```
def getActivationCode(self, id):
    link = 'link to the api'
    r = requests.get(link)
    print(r)
    print(r.json()["data"])
    if r.json()["data"].split(':')[0] != 'STATUS-OK':
        self.getActivationCode(id)
        delay(100)
    return r.json()["data"]
```

Every response data is STATUS-WAIT, but only a first few should be. I also checked it and the api data always changes to STATUS-OK, just my script does not update it for some reason and it keeps telling me that it is still STATUS-WAIT.

Comment: can u share the value of r.json() when STATUS-OK ?

Comment: Add return where you are calling `self.getActivationCode()` again inside the if condition, in your current code you are returning the response of the first request. Add return or store it in a variable to return it at the end of the function.

Comment: it is a string like "data": "STATUS-OK:123123", last 6 digits are random

Comment: Okay, thank you I will try to return it now.

Comment: use `data =  r.json()["data"]` - dont call `json()` more than once - there is no need.

Comment: i will fix this detail but it still does not fix my problem